# Iterator with memory?

Tags: iterator, python

I'm working on an application which use a markov chain.

An example on this code follows:

```
chain = MarkovChain(order=1)
train_seq = ["","hello","this","is","a","beautiful","world"]

for i, word in enum(train_seq):
 chain.train(previous_state=train_seq[i-1],next_state=word)
```

What I am looking for is to iterate over train_seq, but to keep the N last elements.

```
for states in unknown(train_seq,order=1):
 # states should be a list of states, with states[-1] the newest word,
 # and states[:-1] should be the previous occurrences of the iteration.
 chain.train(*states)
```

Hope the description of my problem is clear enough for

Comment: So you're looking to iterate on successive pairs? And what's `unknown`? Is that what you're asking us to fill or is that a function you already have?

Comment: not neccecarily pairs, as I will build markov chains with arbitary orders. Unknown is the mission function which I try to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window` will give you `n` items from `iterable` at a time.

```
from collections import deque

def window(iterable, n=3):
    it = iter(iterable)
    d = deque(maxlen = n)
    for elem in it:
        d.append(elem)
        yield tuple(d)


print [x for x in window([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
# [(1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

If you want the same number of items even the first few times,

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def window(iterable, n=3):
    it = iter(iterable)
    d = deque((next(it) for Null in range(n-1)), n)
    for elem in it:
        d.append(elem)
        yield tuple(d)


print [x for x in window([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

will do that.

Comment: Looks promising! How will this work with a train_seq of 100MB worth of data?

Comment: It's completely unaffected by the size of `iterable`, it's only affected by the size of `n`. How many items do you want to remember at a time?

Comment: I imagine I would use a window size from 1 to around 5

Comment: That's no problem. If it were 100s or 1000s of items, it would be slow because it has to make a tuple every time, but it's fast for just a few items. Keep in mind the current item counts as an item, so a window of `1` would be zero trailing items.

Comment: It may not even be necessary to convert it to a tuple each time depending on what you're doing with it. If you are iterating over all the items in the window (for example, using `sum()`) a deque is actually slightly faster than a tuple or list in my tests, and accessing individual elements is about the same speed for small deques. It's difficult to get back the time you've spent converting it to a tuple.

Comment: Because it uses the same deque the whole time, if you save a reference to it, then look back at it on a later iteration, it will have changed. Converting to a tuple means that you can safely save a reference to the yielded object, and it will be the same even on later iterations. If you'll never need to refer to any of the windows later, it's not necessary to make tuples.

Comment: That's an interesting insight, but I think I'd rather have the caller decide whether an immutable copy of the window is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for w in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
  print w
```

You can also do the following to create an arbitrarily-sized pairs:

```
tuple_size = 2
for w in zip(*(seq[i:] for i in range(tuple_size)))
  print w
```

edit: But it's probably better using the iterative zip:

```
from itertools import izip

tuple_size = 4
for w in izip(*(seq[i:] for i in range(tuple_size)))
  print w
```

I tried this on my system with seq being 10,000,000 integers and the results were fairly instant.

Comment: This requires a copy of the list, and more copies if you want a wider window.

Comment: Speed isn't the issue, you have to hold `tuple_size` copies of it in memory, and he said the sequence was 100mb. This might not be a problem in some situations, but if you have a virtual server with only 1gb of RAM you're going to be under memory pressure pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon yan's answer to avoid copies:

```
from itertools import *

def staggered_iterators(sequence, count):
  iterator = iter(sequence)
  for i in xrange(count):
    result, iterator = tee(iterator)
    yield result
    next(iterator)

tuple_size = 4
for w in izip(*(i for i in takewhile(staggered_iterators(seq, order)))):
  print w
```

Comment: I think you just mean `izip(*staggered_iterators(seq, tuple_size))`. If you look at the equivalent source for `tee` given in the `itertools` docs, this also requires some intermediate storage, and use of several `deque`s. It also doesn't allow for the strict condition of `w[-1]` is the current item, since the third item is `w[-1]` on the first iteration.